# How to get value of nextsibling if element search by specific string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the text which is in the next element of searched element by string.Let me explain by code

```html
<table id="myTable">
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
   <td>foo</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <th>age</th>
   <td>20</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I have to search string if "age" exist. then return 20 as its value.
I tried to search string by contains: But unable to access value

Comment: Don't access elements by their content. Use an `id` or `class` attributes to properly mark them as your target.

Comment: Yes i know that. But I have to search in that way. Can you help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [jQuery next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and [contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to achieve what you need.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($("th:contains(age)").next().html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <td>foo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>age</th>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks its quick and easy.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will go through all the elements that are children of `tr`s and check to see that their text is equal to the search. If it is equal, it assigns the next element to `nextElem`.

```js
let search = "age";
let nextElem;

$('#myTable tr').children().each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() === search)
    nextElem = $(this).next();
});

console.log(nextElem.text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
   <td>foo</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <th>age</th>
   <td>20</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You've already set up the table to display name-value pairs, where each name is contained within `<th>...</th>` and its corresponding value is contained within `<td>...</td>`.

So one approach to this is straightforward Document Object Model navigation, using:

- `getElementsByTagName('th')`
- `getElementsByTagName('td')`

```js
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
var summary = document.getElementsByClassName('summary')[0];
var searchedFor = summary.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
var correspondingResult = summary.getElementsByTagName('p')[1];


function displayResult() {
var returnValue = '';
var searchString = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
var lowerCaseSearchString = searchString.toLowerCase();
var tableRows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (var i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
    var name = tableRows[i].getElementsByTagName('th')[0].textContent.toLowerCase();

    if (name === lowerCaseSearchString) {
        returnValue = tableRows[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0].textContent;
    }

    if (returnValue === '') {
        returnValue = 'No Matches';
    }
}

searchedFor.textContent = 'You searched for... ' + '"' + searchString + '"';
correspondingResult.textContent = 'The corresponding result is... ' + '"' + returnValue + '"';
}

button.addEventListener('click',displayResult,false);
```

```css
table, .search-panel {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
margin-right: 24px;
}

table {
border: 2px solid rgb(127,127,127);
}

th, td {
padding: 12px;
}

th {
text-align: left;
background-color: rgb(191,191,191);
}

th::after {
content:':';
}

.search-results p span {
font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<td>Foo</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Age</th>
<td>20</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>

<div class="search-panel">
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your string here..." value="" />
<button type="button">Search for String</button>
</form>

<div class="summary">
<p>You searched for... </p>
<p>The corresponding result is... </p>
</div>
</div>
```